# 'WinError 10061' when using a sockets function in a tk command

Tags: windows, sockets, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi and thanks for reading this. I know *what* the problem is but I can't figure out how to fix it.

So the problem goes like this (I think), python is trying to run `connect()` before the user inputs the host name(`hostname`) therefore python is trying to connect to a blank host(`''`) which in turn causes a `[WinError 10061]` to happen. I have tried buffering `connect()` with another function(`connect_buffer()`), the error kept on happening, even when I added a `if` statement that set `hostname` to `'localhost'` if `hostname` was blank(`''`), but that didn't work either and turned up the same error.

So my Question is how do I fix this?

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\server\New folder\Tk_cleint.py", line 89, in <module>
    setup_confirm_button = tk.Button(window,text = 'Connect', command = setup())
  File "H:\server\New folder\Tk_cleint.py", line 18, in setup
    create_sock(host, int(port))
  File "H:\server\New folder\Tk_cleint.py", line 36, in create_sock
    connect(cleintsocket, nhost, nport)
  File "H:\server\New folder\Tk_cleint.py", line 27, in connect
    self.connect((hostname, connectingport))
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

And here is my code

```
#---Import statments---#
import socket, os, multiprocessing
import tkinter as tk

#---global variables---#
setup = ''
cleintsocket = ''

#---Defs---#
def setup():
    global host, port, user
    host = setup_host_box.get()
    port = setup_port_box.get()
    user = setup_user_box.get()

def connect_buffer(self, hostname, connectingport):
    connect(self, hostname, connectingport)

def connect(self, hostname, connectingport):
    if hostname == '':
        hostname = 'localhost'
    self.connect((hostname, int(connectingport)))
    print('connected')
    multiprocessing.Process(target = resv()).start()

def create_sock(nhost, nport):
    global cleintsocket
    cleintsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    connect(cleintsocket, nhost, nport)

def send(username, cleintsock):
    '''to send a message'''
    usrmsg = (username + ' - ' + chat_msg_box.get()).encode()
    cleintsock.send(usrmsg)

def resv(sock):
    '''resive subscript, run through mutiprosses module'''
    while True:
        rmsg = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        chat_msg_display_text.insert('end.0.', rmsg)

def chat():
    '''loads chat page'''
    setup_host_text.pack_forget()
    setup_host_box.pack_forget()
    setup_port_text.pack_forget()
    setup_port_box.pack_forget()
    setup_user_text.pack_forget()
    setup_user_box.pack_forget()
    setup_confirm_button.pack_forget()
    chat_msg_display_text.pack()
    chat_msg_box.pack()
    chat_msg_send_button.pack()

def start():
    '''starts the setup page'''
    setup_host_text.pack()
    setup_host_box.pack()
    setup_port_text.pack()
    setup_port_box.pack()
    setup_user_text.pack()
    setup_user_box.pack()
    setup_confirm_button.pack()

def send_button_callback():
    '''add a buffer to allow time for 'cleintsocket' to be defined in "create_sock()"'''
    send(user, cleintsocket)

#---TK Setup---#
#--window setup--#
window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Chat')
window.geometry('600x600')
window.configure(background='#ffffff')
#--connection setup page--#
setup_host_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Host')
setup_host_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_port_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Port')
setup_port_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_user_text = tk.Label(window, text = 'Username')
setup_user_box = tk.Entry(window, bg = '#ffffff')
setup_confirm_button = tk.Button(window,text = 'Connect', command = setup())
#--chat page--#
chat_msg_box = tk.Entry(window, bg='#ffffff')
chat_msg_send_button = tk.Button(window, text = 'send', command = send_button_callback)
chat_msg_display_text = tk.Text(window, width=600, height=500, wrap = 'word')
#--------------#

start()
```

and here are some links to questions that didn't help:

[WinError 10049: The requested address is not valid in its context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857942/winerror-10049-the-requested-address-is-not-valid-in-its-context)

[Connecting to myself through my public IP through TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043413/connecting-to-myself-through-my-public-ip-through-tcp)

[Webscraping with Python: WinError 10061: Target machine actively refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271180/webscraping-with-python-winerror-10061-target-machine-actively-refused)

Thank you to anyone who helps.

Comment: @Pythonisa I'll try it thanks

Comment: @Pythonista  Thanks it worked just add it as an answer and ill click the tick

Comment: Edited answer for why it's freezing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your setup_confirm_button you're using `command = setup()` this should be `command = setup` or `command = lambda: setup()`

By calling `setup()` you're actually calling the function instead of setting it as a reference to the function for the command, and it's running your function then instead of on the button click.

The reason using `lambda: setup()` also works is because `lambda` creates an anonymous function.

Also, in your multiprocessing process you're likewise calling `resv()` instead of passing `resv` this is calling the function with a while loop and blocking the main event loop.

Comment: Thank you you have been such a great help!